# About the camera calibration parameters

Tags: ros, calibration, camera-info, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have been looking at the camera calibration parameters generated during the calibration and the explanation of the cameraInfo parameters in the ROS wiki.

I can't figure out what the K' matrix is and how the projection matrix is obtained. I thought it would be given by P=K*R but the math doesn't add up.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/102641/about-the-camera-calibration-parameters/) by [sofiad](https://answers.ros.org/users/8786/sofiad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2013-11-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [CameraInfo message definition](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html) describes each of the parameters in great detail.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2